# Question about meaning of "get a big picture"

Tags: expressions

> The other thing is our hand position when we’re driving. It’s nice, soft hands are very important in learning to drive. We don’t want a death grip on that wheel. We want nice, soft hands, like pretty much anything that you do in sports, your hands have to be nice and soft. If your hands are soft and you’re not real tense, you’ll find that you have the ability to steer a car much, much better.
>
> You also want to be able to **get the big picture** when we’re driving. We don’t want to stare at anything because when you drive, you will follow your eyes. Okay? So if you’re looking to the right or you’re looking to the left and you’re staring at that portion of the vehicle, that’s the way the vehicle will move. When people drive a car for the first time, they have a difficult ability to understand how far they are away from the vehicle to the right, and that’s because the right side of the vehicle is a little further away from you than the left. So invariably what they usually do is they stare down to the right side, and what happens when you stare to the right, your car will go to the right. So you want to pick your eyes up. You want to keep your eyes ahead of you looking out ahead and you’ll find that you follow your eyes. So if your eyes are straight ahead the car will have a better chance of going straight.

What does it mean **to get a big picture** in a driving context?

Comment: It means the same as in any other context; "big picture" is a known idiom that you can look up.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you get the big picture while driving, you get an overall look around yourself. You see what's up ahead, to your right, to your left and even behind you. Just quick glances up, to your side mirrors and to your rear view mirror help keep you informed of what's going on around you while you drive.

Comment: And not just what the car just ahead of you is doing, but the cars even further in front (and off to the left/right/etc). This is related to the phrase  ignoring the forest for the trees. If you're focused on the car in front of you, you may miss the fact that cars farther ahead are braking or that a stop light has turned red, etc.